# How to negate an entire expression using EL

Tags: jsp, el, negation

Similar to Java, I need to negate an entire expression in JSP using EL.

For eg in JAVA:

```
if(!((a.equals("coding")) && (b.equals("forever")))){
     //do this
}
```

what is the equivalent statment in EL for this ?
I tried the below line but it throwed an error.

```
 <c:if test="${(ne((a eq 'coding') && (b eq 'forever')))}">
     //do this
</c:if>
```

Comment: please try `not` instead of `ne`   `(not((a eq 'coding')...`

Comment: RRN, what exception did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just rewrite the logic:

```
!((a.equals("coding")) && (b.equals("forever")))
```

is the same as

```
!a.equals("coding") || !b.equals("forever")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<c:if test="${((a ne 'coding') or (b ne 'forever'))}">
     //do this
</c:if>
```